# Passing data to nuxt fetch, store dispatch not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to pass in a parameter to store.$dispatch but if I call the data from data it says the data was undefined.

Why does this not work:

```
data () {
  return {
    year: '2019'
  }
},
async fetch({store}) {
    await store.dispatch('posts/fetchAll', this.year)
},
```

But this does:

```
async fetch({store}) {
    await store.dispatch('posts/fetchAll', '2019')
},
```

I'm using veux and nuxt.

**Update**

So from the first answer I can see why what I was doing wouldn't work. But there must be a way to use fetch and update the query based on data? Say I had a form select and I wanted users to be able to change the data based on the year?

Answer (score 2):

The docs says:

> Warning: You don't have access of the component instance through this
>   inside fetch because it is called before initiating the component.

You cant access `this` because fetch is called on server side, and your `data()` is on client side

Comment: ah ok thanks, so how would you change the value based on say a form field?

Comment: do you want to store your data from a form into your store?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be. Basically I want a user to be able to select a year on the page and this is then passed to the store to update the api call